# Trap: can't su as root, can't change group to wheel, ssh as root prohibited

Tags: security, authentication, freebsd, login, rescue

Is this a trap? I made these steps in FreeBSD 10:

> 1) ssh as root prohibited
>
> 2) logged as user
>
> 3) su as root
>
> 4) as root **chsh** changed name of user **"user"** to **"luser"**
>
> 5) exit from root

And from this moment I can't **su root** cause the **luser** is not in the **wheel** group and I can't change group in **/etc/group** because I have no privileges for doing that.

What can I do to login as root ?

Answer (score 22):

You can do any one of these four things:

- Log in as a user that is in the `wheel` group and fix it from there
- Log in as root from the console/ILO
- Boot off of a CD, mount /etc and fix /etc/group
- Restore /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow from the most recent backup

Answer (score 3):

There is  no need for live cd or usb stick.
You could boot into single user mode, mount the filesystems `mount -a` and set/change the root password `passwd`

Single user mode is a mode for just one user, root. You can boot into single user mode without typing in the root password.

In BSD booting into single user mode is usually an option in the boot menu.

In linux booting into single user mode could be achieved by setting `single` as a kernel option. (e.g. in grub, select the boot line, press `e` to edit, change the init parameter, press `c` to continue booting.)

In LILO using the LILO boot prompt (press [Ctrl]-[x]  if you're in a graphical interface) and type `linux single`

If this doesn't work for an old kernel, you can also specify `--init=/bin/bash` then you get a root bash shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot from a live cd or usb drive, mount your system partition, modify the nessecary files, boot your system again.